# Display records from one table which is not in another table by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012 Express for following query.

**Table_A**

```
CLIENT              TYPEOFWORK               ACTIVITY
-----------------------------------------------------
CLIENT A            WORK A                   ACTIVITY A
CLIENT A            WORK B                   ACTIVITY B
CLIENT A            WORK C                   ACTIVITY C
CLIENT A            WORK C                   NULL
```

**Table_B**

```
CLIENT               TYPEOFWORK                 STATUS
--------------------------------------------------------
CLIENT A             WORK C                     COMPLETED
```

I want to display records from `Table_A` which is not in `Table_B` by `client` and `typeofwork`.

I need following output.

```
CLIENT             TYPEOFWORK                 ACTIVITY
------------------------------------------------------
CLIENT A            WORK A                    ACTIVITY A
CLIENT A            WORK B                    ACTIVITY B
```

I tried with `NOT IN` but it works only with one column

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: Use `NOT EXISTS`

Here is the full scenario for the ease:

```
CREATE TABLE #table_a(CLIENT VARCHAR(50), TYPEOFWORK VARCHAR(50), ACTIVITY VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #table_a VALUES
('CLIENT A', 'WORK A', 'ACTIVITY A'),
('CLIENT A', 'WORK B', 'ACTIVITY B'),
('CLIENT A', 'WORK C', 'ACTIVITY C'),
('CLIENT A', 'WORK C', NULL)

CREATE TABLE #table_b(CLIENT VARCHAR(50), TYPEOFWORK VARCHAR(50), STATUS VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #table_b values
('CLIENT A', 'WORK C', 'COMPLETED')

SELECT 
    a.client,
    a.typeofwork,
    a.activity
FROM #table_a a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #table_b b 
                 WHERE a.client = b.client AND a.typeofwork = b.typeofwork)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
client      typeofwork  activity
----------------------------------
CLIENT A    WORK A      ACTIVITY A
CLIENT A    WORK B      ACTIVITY B
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the client columns to match and the typeofwork to not be the same, is that correct? If so, you can left join on your column conditions like this:

```
SELECT A.CLIENT, A.TYPEOFWORK, A.STATUS
FROM TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B ON B.CLIENT = A.CLIENT AND 
A.TYPEOFWORK <> B.TYPEOFWORK
WHERE B.CLIENT IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.CLIENT, A.TYPEOFWORK, A.ACTIVITY
FROM TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B 
ON A.CLIENT = B.CLIENT 
AND A.TYPEOFWORK = B.TYPEOFWORK
WHERE B.CLIENT IS NULL 
OR B.TYPEOFWORK IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Table_B WHERE CLIENT = Table_A.CLIENT AND TYPEOFWORK = Table_A.TYPEOFWORK
  )
```

Hopefully it serves your purpose. See demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc6bf6/1)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Select * from Table_A 
where Client NOT IN (Select Client from Table_B)
and TypeOFWork NOT IN (Select TypeOfWork from Table_B)
```

Comment: Is there any other option without using 'NOT IN'?Because I have to use same query two times. I have just shown a demo tables but actual tables are very large.

Comment: You could use " NOT EXISTS" instead . Performance wise, it depends if your table has null or not.

Comment: No it does not suits my requirements.

Comment: Isn't that what you want for your desired output? I don't see how it doesn't answer your question. If your table is really large, you could try with Exists clause but it's hard to say if it improves the performance of the query.

Comment: i HAVE NOT DOWNVOTED ANYONE. THOUGH I UPVOTED ALREADY DOWNVOTED ACCEPTED ANSWER

Answer (score -1):

try the following:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B ON B.CLIENT = A.CLIENT AND A.TYPEOFWORK = B.TYPEOFWORK
WHERE B.[STATUS] IS NULL
```

Thanks.

Comment: This will display all records from TABLE_A

Comment: try this:

SELECT A.*
FROM TABLE_A A
WHERE CLIENT+TYPEOFWORK NOT IN (SELECT CLIENT+TYPEOFWORK FROM TABLE_B)

Comment: I don't think my down voted query will produce any different than the accepted answer.